# MySQL backup using AutoMySQLBackup from slave to remote machine

Tags: mysql, mysql-backup

I am trying to setup daily backup for MySQL database from slave server or MySQL instance. My database is a mixture of InnoDb and MyISAM tables. I have installed [AutoMySQLBackup](https://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/) on another machine. I am trying to take a full backup and a daily incremental backup of a  MySQL database from that machine with the help of AutoMySQLBackup.

Comment: and what do you wnat to do?

Comment: This is just for your information that there is no incremental backup for myisam...so any tool will take innodb tables incremental backup but full backup of myisam tables any time.....so if you have any myisam big table then it can be problematic.

Comment: What have you tried so far? In which part of the process are you having trouble? Any error in particular?

Comment: I have tried automysqlbackup from remote client and it has limitation.I wrote a script which is doing this job very nicely but i was looking for nice tool. And i don't want to use Percona XtraBackup . That is complex i think it will not be easy to understand my trainee.

Answer (score -1):

Mysql Full backup:-

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.12/en/mysqlbackup.full.html

> Options on Command Line or in Configuration File?
>
> For clarity, the examples in this manual often show some of the
>   command-line options that are used with the mysqlbackup commands. For
>   convenience and consistency, you can include those options that remain
>   unchanged for most backup jobs into the [mysqlbackup] section of the
>   MySQL configuration file that you supply to mysqlbackup. mysqlbackup
>   also picks up the options from the [mysqld] section if they are
>   present there. Putting the options into a configuration file can
>   simplify backup administration for you: for example, putting port
>   information into a configuration file, you can avoid the need to edit
>   your backup scripts each time the database instance switches to a
>   different port. See Chapter 14, Configuration Files and Parameters for
>   details about the use of configuration files.
>
> Output in Single Directory or Timestamped Subdirectories?
>
> For convenience, the --with-timestamp option creates uniquely named
>   subdirectories under the backup directory to hold the output from each
>   backup job. The timestamped subdirectories make it simpler to
>   establish retention periods, allowing easy removal and archiving of
>   backup data that has passed a certain age.
>
> If you do use a single backup directory (that is, if you omit the
>   --with-timestamp option), either specify a new unique directory name for each backup job, or specify the --force option to overwrite
>   existing backup files.
>
> For incremental backups that uses the --incremental-base option to
>   specify the directory containing the previous backup, in order to make
>   the directory names predictable, you might prefer to not use the
>   --with-timestamp option and generate a sequence of directory names with your backup script instead .
>
> Always Full Backup, or Full Backup plus Incremental Backups?
>
> If your InnoDB data volume is small, or if your database is so busy
>   that a high percentage of data changes between backups, you might want
>   to run a full backup each time. However, you can usually save time and
>   storage space by running periodic full backups and then several
>   incremental backups in between them, as described in Section 4.3.2,
>   “Making a Differential or Incremental Backup”.
>
> Use Compression or Not?
>
> Creating a compressed backup can save you considerable storage space
>   and reduce I/O usage significantly. And with the LZ4 compression
>   method (introduced since release 3.10), the overhead for processing
>   compression is quite low. In cases where database backups are moving
>   from a faster disk system where the active database files sit to a
>   possibly slower storage, compression will often significantly lower
>   the overall backup time. It can result in reduced restoration time as
>   well. In general, we recommend LZ4 compression over no compression for
>   most users, as LZ4-based backups often finish in a shorter time
>   period. However, test out MySQL Enterprise Backup within your
>   environment to determine what is the most efficient approach.

The incremental backup feature is primarily intended for InnoDB tables, or non-InnoDB tables that are read-only or rarely updated. For non-InnoDB files, the entire file is included in an incremental backup if that file changed since the previous backup.

You cannot perform incremental backups with the --compress option.

Incremental backups detect changes at the level of pages in the InnoDB data files, as opposed to table rows; each page that has changed is backed up. Thus, the space and time savings are not exactly proportional to the percentage of changed InnoDB rows or columns.

When an InnoDB table is dropped and you do a subsequent incremental backup, the apply-log step removes the corresponding .ibd file from the full backup directory. Since the backup program cannot have the same insight into the purpose of non-InnoDB files, when a non-InnoDB file is removed between the time of a full backup and a subsequent incremental backup, the apply-log step does not remove that file from the full backup directory. Thus, restoring a backup could result in a deleted file reappearing.

> Creating Incremental Backups Using Only the Redo Log
>
> The --incremental-with-redo-log-only might offer some benefits over
>   the --incremental option for creating an incremental backup:
>
> The changes to InnoDB tables are determined based on the contents of
>   the InnoDB redo log. Since the redo log files have a fixed size that
>   you know in advance, it can require less I/O to read the changes from
>   them than to scan the InnoDB tablespace files to locate the changed
>   pages, depending on the size of your database, amount of DML activity,
>   and size of the redo log files.
>
> Since the redo log files act as a circular buffer, with records of
>   older changes being overwritten as new DML operations take place, you
>   must take new incremental backups on a predictable schedule dictated
>   by the size of the log files and the amount of redo data generated for
>   your workload. Otherwise, the redo log might not reach back far enough
>   to record all the changes since the previous incremental backup, in
>   which case mysqlbackup will quickly determine that it cannot proceed
>   and will return an error. Your backup script should be able to catch
>   that error and then perform an incremental backup with the
>   --incremental option instead.
>
> For example:
>
> To calculate the size of the redo log, issue the command SHOW
>   VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_log_file%' and, based on the output, multiply
>   the innodb_log_file_size setting by the value of
>   innodb_log_files_in_group. To compute the redo log size at the
>   physical level, look into the datadir directory of the MySQL instance
>   and sum up the sizes of the files matching the pattern ib_logfile*.
>
> The InnoDB LSN value corresponds to the number of bytes written to the
>   redo log. To check the LSN at some point in time, issue the command
>   SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS and look under the LOG heading. While
>   planning your backup strategy, record the LSN values periodically and
>   subtract the earlier value from the current one to calculate how much
>   redo data is generated each hour, day, and so on.
>
> Prior to MySQL 5.5, it was common practice to keep the redo logs
>   fairly small to avoid a long startup time when the MySQL server was
>   killed rather than shut down normally. With MySQL 5.5 and higher, the
>   performance of crash recovery is significantly improved, as described
>   in Optimizing InnoDB Configuration Variables, so that you can make
>   your redo log files bigger if that helps your backup strategy and your
>   database workload.
>
> This type of incremental backup is not so forgiving of too-low
>   --start-lsn values as the standard --incremental option. For example, you cannot make a full backup and then make a series of
>   --incremental-with-redo-log-only backups all using the same --start-lsn value. Make sure to specify the precise end LSN of the previous backup as the start LSN of the next incremental backup; do
>   not use arbitrary values.
>
> Note To ensure the LSN values match up exactly between successive
>   incremental backups, it is recommended that you always use the
>   --incremental-base option when you use the --incremental-with-redo-log-only option.
>
> To judge whether this type of incremental backup is practical and
>   efficient for a particular MySQL instance:
>
> Measure how fast the data changes within the InnoDB redo log files.
>   Check the LSN periodically to decide how much redo data accumulates
>   over the course of some number of hours or days.
>
> Compare the rate of redo log accumulation with the size of the redo
>   log files. Use this ratio to see how often to take an incremental
>   backup, in order to avoid the likelihood of the backup failing because
>   the historical data are not available in the redo log. For example, if
>   you are producing 1GB of redo log data per day, and the combined size
>   of your redo log files is 7GB, you would schedule incremental backups
>   more frequently than once a week. You might perform incremental
>   backups every day or two, to avoid a potential issue when a sudden
>   flurry of updates produced more redo than usual.
>
> Benchmark incremental backup times using both the --incremental and
>   --incremental-with-redo-log-only options, to confirm if the redo log backup technique performs faster and with less overhead than the
>   traditional incremental backup method. The result could depend on the
>   size of your data, the amount of DML activity, and the size of your
>   redo log files. Do your testing on a server with a realistic data
>   volume and a realistic workload. For example, if you have huge redo
>   log files, reading them in the course of an incremental backup could
>   take as long as reading the InnoDB data files using the traditional
>   incremental technique. Conversely, if your data volume is large,
>   reading all the data files to find the few changed pages could be less
>   efficient than processing the much smaller redo log files.
>
> Other Considerations for Incremental Backups
>
> The incremental backup feature is primarily intended for InnoDB
>   tables, or non-InnoDB tables that are read-only or rarely updated.
>   Incremental backups detect changes at the level of pages in the InnoDB
>   data files, as opposed to table rows; each page that has changed is
>   backed up. Thus, the space and time savings are not exactly
>   proportional to the percentage of changed InnoDB rows or columns.
>
> For non-InnoDB files, the entire file is included in an incremental
>   backup if that file has changed since the previous backup, which means
>   the savings for backup resources are less significant when comparing
>   with the case with InnoDB tables.
>
> You cannot perform incremental backups with the --compress option.
>
> When making an incremental backup that is based on a backup (full or
>   incremental) created using the --no-locking option, use the
>   --skip-binlog option to skip the backing up of the binary log, as binary log information will be unavailable to mysqlbackup in that
>   situation.

Examples of Incremental Backups

This example uses mysqlbackup to make an incremental backup of a MySQL server, including all databases and tables. We show two alternatives, one using the --incremental-base option and the other using the --start-lsn option.

With the --incremental-base option, you do not have to keep track of LSN values between one backup and the next. Instead, you can just specify the directory of the previous backup (either full or incremental), and mysqlbackup figures out the starting point for this backup based on the metadata of the earlier one. Because you need a known set of directory names, you might want to use hardcoded names or generate a sequence of names in your own backup script, rather than using the --with-timestamp option.

```
$ mysqlbackup --defaults-file=/home/pekka/.my.cnf --incremental \
  --incremental-base=dir:/incr-backup/wednesday \
  --incremental-backup-dir=/incr-backup/thursday \
  backup
```

...many lines of output...
mysqlbackup: Backup created in directory '/incr-backup/thursday'
mysqlbackup: start_lsn: 2654255717
mysqlbackup: incremental_base_lsn: 2666733462
mysqlbackup: end_lsn: 2666736714z

101208 17:14:58 mysqlbackup: mysqlbackup completed OK!
Note that if your last backup was a single-file instead of a directory backup, you can still use --incremental-base by specifying for dir:directory_path the location of the temporary directory you supplied with the --backup-dir option during the full backup.

As an alternative to specifying --incremental-base=dir:directory_path, you can tell mysqlbackup to query the end_lsn value from the last successful backup as recorded in the backup_history table on the server using --incremental-base=history:last_backup (this required that the last backup was made with mysqlbackup connected to the server).

You can also use the --start-lsn option to specify where the incremental backup should start. You have to record the LSN of the previous backup reported by mysqlbackup at the end of the backup:

mysqlbackup: Was able to parse the log up to lsn 2654255716
The number is also recorded in the meta/backup_variables.txt file in the folder specified by --backup-dir during the backup. Supply then that number to mysqlbackup using the --start-lsn option. The incremental backup then includes all changes that came after the specified LSN. Since then the location of the previous backup is not very significant then, you can use --with-timestamp to create named subdirectories automatically.

```
$ mysqlbackup --defaults-file=/home/pekka/.my.cnf --incremental \
  --start-lsn=2654255716 \
  --with-timestamp \
  --incremental-backup-dir=/incr-backup \
  backup
```

...many lines of output...
mysqlbackup: Backup created in directory '/incr-backup/2010-12-08_17-14-48'
mysqlbackup: start_lsn: 2654255717
mysqlbackup: incremental_base_lsn: 2666733462
mysqlbackup: end_lsn: 2666736714

101208 17:14:58 mysqlbackup: mysqlbackup completed OK!
To create an incremental backup image instead, use the following command, specifying with --incremental-backup-dir a temporary directory for storing the metadata for the backup and some temporary files:

```
$ mysqlbackup --defaults-file=/home/pekka/.my.cnf --incremental \
  --start-lsn=2654255716 \
  --with-timestamp \
  --incremental-backup-dir=/incr-tmp \
 --backup-image=/incr-backup/incremental_image.bi
  backup-to-image
```

In the following example though, because --backup-image does not provide a full path to the image file to be created, the incremental backup image is created under the folder specified by --incremental-backup-dir:

```
$ mysqlbackup --defaults-file=/home/pekka/.my.cnf --incremental \
  --start-lsn=2654255716 \
  --with-timestamp \
  --incremental-backup-dir=/incr-images \
 --backup-image=incremental_image1.bi
  backup-to-image
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.7/en/mysqlbackup.incremental.html

Comment: I don't think pasting a whole document into stackoverflow is a good idea.